# Something wrong with dynamic memory on my ADT

Tags: c++, tree, dynamic-memory-allocation, delete-operator

I'm an student of computer science and for a work I have made a ADT which store Strings in a Generic Tree whit a defined prefix (first letters of strings which start the same are stored only one time) and I've tested it so now it seems to work fine. Nevertheless, now I need to do a program which make some instances of the ADT with different sizes of prefix and I'm getting some Troubles.

If I write:

```
      Refranes *ref1 ; 
      Refranes *ref2 ; 

      ref1 = new Refranes(3) ; 
      ref2 = new Refranes(4) ; 

      ref1->Insertar("try1") ; // Insert "try1" on the tree
      ref2->Insertar("try2") ; 

      cout << *ref1 << *ref2 ;
```

everything works fine, but If I try:

```
        Refranes *ref ; 

        ref = new Refranes(3) ; 
        ref->Insertar("try1") ; 
        cout <<*ref ; 
        delete ref ; 

        ref = new Refranes(4) ; 
        ref->Insertar("try2") ; 
        cout << *ref ;
```

that prints "try2" over and over again... and I'm not able to find what's going wrong...

I'm not sure if I am using pointers in a wrong way or if my ADT isn't correct..

I doubt that this will be a failure on the ADT because, as I shown, make new Refranes on differents pointers works fine, so I think the problem is when I try to reuse the pointer and call to delete operator... What makes me confused if that... if I've deleted the memory associated to the pointer and called to new operator... how what I've done early can modify the behavior of the new instance?

I let you some pieces of my code which would be necessary in order to understand what's going wro
ng:

1: ADT "Refranes" which contains a GeneralTree

```
    private:
        ArbolGeneral<string> ab;// general tree
        int len_prefijo;
        int n_ref;// number of string stored
        int caracteres_totales; // number of characters stored
```

it have no Destructor because ArbolGeneral does and the rest of his attributes are of int type.

2. ArbolGeneral attributes and destructor:
          private:
           struct nodo { // nod of the three
             Tbase etiqueta; //

   ```
         nodo *izqda; // left child 

         nodo *drcha; //  rigth brother 

          nodo *padre; // father nod 
       };

       struct nodo *laraiz; // root 

       void destruir(nodo * n){ // destroy meethod
           if ( n != 0 ){
       destruir(n->izqda) ;
       destruir(n->drcha) ; 
       delete n ;
     }

       ~ArbolGeneral(){
           destruir(laraiz) ; 
       }
   ```

I think the rest of the ADT works correctly.